# Retain the columns whose column heading is coloured and delete the rest

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to read or find the column heading that is coloured with any colour and retain only those and delete the rest.

Each time data varies any column name or header could be any colour.

I get

> error 438 "object doesn't support this property method"

at the line `Set Body = ........`

I am not able to figure out if my logic for the select case method is correct or if an If statement would solve the problem.

```vb
Option Explicit
    
Sub delcol()
    Dim header As Range, body As Range, col As Long, found As Boolean, wsh As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    Dim HasColor As Range
    Dim currentColumn As Integer
    
    Set header = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").UsedRange.Rows(1).Columns
    Set body = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Offset(1).Columns
    
    For col = 1 To header.Count    
        found = HasColor(body(col), vbGreen)
    
        Select Case header
            Case Is = found
    
            Case Else
                If InStr(1, _
                  ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value, _
                  "found", vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
                    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Columns(col).Delete
                End If
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: How do these cells get the color? Manually, via `VBA` or via `Conditional Formatting`? Is the code located in the `ActiveWorkbook`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Delete Columns Not Containing Specified Color in Header

- This is a beginner-intermediate solution which will calculate the last column in a specified worksheet using its header row. Then it will loop from the last to the specified first column and check each cell in header row if its fill color is NOT green (`vbGreen`). If so (not green), it will hide/delete the column.
- The code will only work for manually set colors in the header row (incl. via `VBA`). It will not work for `Conditional Formatting`.
- The code is to be copied into a standard module, e.g. `Module1`.
- It is crucial that if this is to happen in the workbook containing this code, that all occurrences of `ActiveWorkbook` be replaced with `ThisWorkbook`.
- Before running this code, adjust the two constants: `hRow` (Header Row) and `First` (First Column).
- Note that you **cannot** undo this operation. Therefore the code uses `Hidden` instead of `Delete` for testing purposes. If the code works for you, out-comment the line `ws.Columns(j).Hidden = True` and uncomment the line `ws.Columns(j).Delete`.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub deleteColumns()
    ' Define constants.
    Const hRow As Long = 1
    Const First As String = "A"
    ' Define worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Main")
    ' Show all columns.
    ws.Columns.Hidden = False
    ' Calculate First Column.
    Dim FirstCol As Long
    FirstCol = ws.Columns(First).Column
    ' Calculate Last Column.
    Dim LastCol As Long
    LastCol = ws.Cells(hRow, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ' Declare variables.
    Dim j As Long
    ' Loop through columns from First to Last Column.
    For j = LastCol To FirstCol Step -1
        ' Check color in current cell.
        If Not ws.Cells(hRow, j).Interior.Color = vbGreen Then
            ' Test with 'Hidden', later change to 'Delete'.
            ws.Columns(j).Hidden = True
            'ws.Columns(j).Delete
        End If
    Next j
End Sub

Sub showColumns()
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Columns.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for detail explanation it works thanks... @VBasic2008

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the whole code? I can't see a line with

```
SetBody=...
```

However, what does your

```
HasColor(body(col), vbGreen)
```

do exactly?

One question though: You're trying to achieve that all columns, where the header (e.g. *top cell*) which is **not** in any color, are deleted upon execution, right?